# Custom Button user control in xaml in binding color

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp

I created a custom template having animating hovers and click colors the code for template is as follows
http://pastebin.com/6jKYYygD
and my usercontrol xaml code is as follows
http://pastebin.com/2GHxvnmu
and cs code as follows

```
namespace FrontEnd.Views
{
    public sealed partial class IconButton : UserControl
    {
        public IconButton()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(IconButton), null);

        public Symbol Icon
        {
            get { return (Symbol)GetValue(IconProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(Symbol), typeof(IconButton), null);

        public Brush BackgroundColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(BackgroundColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackgroundColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(IconButton), null);

        public Brush ForegroundColor
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(ForegroundColorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ForegroundColorProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundColorProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ForegroundColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(IconButton), null);


    }
}
```

when I bind BackgroundColor to background property of button it showss that (Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color) does not exist. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's you color coming from? Did you set the Alpha in it?

Comment: The Color Comes from Colors enum

Comment: Try setting it with the Alpha, for example "Black" is "#FF000000"